# Локализация контента сайта

Tags: wordpress

Как удалить вот такие последствия переводов плагина wordpress qTranslate X? все эти скобки лишние.
[image: скриншот-1]
И как лучше организовывать мультиязычность сайта из 2х языков всего? стоит ли разделить сайт на поддомены и вести отдельные настройки сайтов или писать всё в одном. что и когда удобно?

Comment: >  все эти скобки лишние.

Это называется [шорткоды](https://codex.wordpress.org/ru:Shortcode_API). *Это базовые вещи, которые нужно знать разработчику ВП-сайтов*.

> И как лучше организовывать мультиязычность сайта из 2х языков всего?

Зачем тогда удалять что уже есть, если нужна мультиязычность?

Comment: да. шорткоды. спасибо. я не разработчик. поэтому не знаю. просто помогаю с сайтом человеку. удалять? можно и не удалять. вопрос тут пока спорный. вдруг английская часть не будет настолько читаемой. сейчас берется в обхват большая часть предполагаемых читателей. есть же вариант создания на поддоменах или вообще на других доменных зонах - как те же сайты гугл. под свои страны сделаны сайты. со своим личным функционалом. вот и может стоит более точно решить как создавать мультиязычный вариант чтобы потом поздно разгребать не было

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А никак. Только аккуратным поиском и заменой по базе, с помощью специальных средств, например, [Database Search and Replace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).

Характерная черта вот этих всех недоплагинов перевода типа qTranslate X, Globus и т.д. - после деактивации они оставляют грязные следы своей деятельности везде, где только можно.

В отличие от них, WPML при отключении оставляет сайт в нетронутом виде на основном языке. Так происходит потому, что он не гадит в каждый пост, а создаёт переводы в отдельных постах, которые связаны в базе с постом на основном языке.

Вам не надо беспокоиться о том, переведены ли все страницы или нет. WPML автоматически сделает переход на страницу основного языка, если перевода не существует.

Теперь представьте ситуацию, когда вы сами создали несколько доменов (без плагинов перевода), скопировали туда все тексты, и начали постепенно переводить. Но что делать, если вы захотели внести изменения на странице на основном языке, которая ещё не переведена? Вам опять придётся её копировать на все домены переводов вручную.

А что делать, когда вам нужно изменить структуру меню? Готовьтесь повторить то же самое на всех доменах переводов.

И таких проблем при "переводе вручную" возникает масса. WPML решает их автоматически, поддерживая нужные связи с помощью своих таблиц в базе данных.

Действуя в рамках одной фактической установки WordPress, WPML может отображать структуру переводов по-разному, например:

```
http://site.org/page/?lang=de
http://site.org/de/page
http://de.site.org
```

Эти варианты задаются в настройках.

Да, WPML [платный](https://wpml.org/purchase/), но его возможности окупаются моментально. Да и $29 не та цена, на которую можно жаловаться.

Comment: Не надо называть эти плагины недоплагинами. У них просто другой принцип и подход, нежели в WMPL. Polylang и нек др. И иногда этот подход больше подходит, чем разные посты. А рекламировать при этом WPML,  ну вообще некрасиво. Тем более что цена - это обновление только на год.

Comment: Я высказал свою точку зрения. Считаю указанные мной плагины перевода недоразумением. Рекламы я тут не вижу. Что же теперь, вообще ничего не хвалить? Впрочем, если считаешь мой ответ рекламой, жми на тревогу, отмечал его как спам, пусть модераторы разбираются.

Comment: я думаю каждый по своему в чем то прав. такие плагины я не уважаю. они сильно засоряют сайт и тем самым при случаи вызывают больше проблем чем их решение. однако они бесплатные. за бесплатно мало кто вообще решится создавать полноценный плагин чтобы он работал нормально и с этого ничего не имел автор. но. за плату. плагин должен быть уже на 99-100% более чем идеальным. кроме того, бывает выбор - нужен ли платный вариант. сайт пока на саморазвитии. просто для удобства чтения имеет всего 2 языка. но я учту эти оба мнения.

Comment: @BiLBerry ничего они не "засоряют". У них ДРУГОЙ подход к мультиязычности. В нек случаях "шорткотная" технология бывает целесообразнее, чем "разнопостовая". И бесплатность тут вообще не причём. Тот же WPML за 30$/год ни разу не лучше (даже убогей) бесплатного Polylang-а, который работает по тому же принципу что и WPML.

Comment: @KAGGDesign почему это реклама (да ещё очень не красивая):. 1. ТС  спрашивал "как удалить", а не "какой выбрать". 2. То что ты написал -  от незнания возможностей qTranslate и в основном не соответствует действительности. Кроме первого предложения всё остальное... фи. Да и первое переложение.. только один из вариантов.

Comment: @SeVlad напиши ответ лучше

Comment: @KAGGDesign мне не до того, да и не вижу смысла.